# Would a circuit breaker feature always execute one block after the trigger is detected?

Tags: dapps, defi, stablecoins

Lets say I had a Dapp that used a popular stablecoin whereby the stablecoin had a freeze function. Then say I wanted to detect if the stablecoin accounts were frozen and then circuit break the Dapp.

Assume the stablecoin did not have a native function for this trigger detection. Also assume that the stablecoin issuer *never* alerts people before it executes the freeze.

Would it be that by absolute neccesity the trigger could only be detected 1 block later? Or is it possible to detect it in the same block?

Consider for example Tether and USDC

Thank you

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the question, but would it not just be a matter of transaction position in the block. i.e. if an account is frozen with a transaction in position 1, then that account now acting on that updated state attempting to transfer with a tx in pos 2, would fail, as would any other contract call involving a check on that state.